# Pushing and Popping structs/classes using Ptr<T> in C#

Tags: c#, pointers, graphics, data-structures, xna

I'm trying to simplify vector graphics management in XNA; currently by incorporating state preservation. **The goal is to avoid writing 2X lines of push/pull code in order to preserve only X draw states.**
I would hope to do this by having a client give class/struct refs he wants preserved through his drawing.

Also note that many beginner-programmers will be using this, so forcing lambda expressions or other advanced C# features to be used in client code is not a good idea.

---

I attempted to accomplish my goal by using [Daniel Earwicker's Ptr class](http://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2008/05/06/pointers-to-value-types-in-c/):

```
    public class Ptr<T>
    {
        Func<T> getter;
        Action<T> setter;

        public Ptr(Func<T> g, Action<T> s)
        {
            getter = g;
            setter = s;
        }

        public T Deref
        {
            get { return getter(); }
            set { setter(value); }
        }
    }
```

an extension method:

```
        //doesn't work for structs since this is just syntatic sugar
        public static Ptr<T> GetPtr <T> (this T obj) {
            return new Ptr<T>( ()=> obj, v=> obj=v );
        }
```

and a Push Function:

```
        //returns a Pop Action for later calling
        public static Action Push <T> (ref T structure) where T: struct
        {
            T pushedValue = structure; //copies the struct data
            Ptr<T> p = structure.GetPtr();

            return new Action( ()=> {p.Deref = pushedValue;} );
        }
```

However this doesn't work as stated in the code.

**How might I accomplish my goal?**

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to accomplish, but Earwicker's Ptr construct is not a pointer at all. It's a trick to promote a local variable to a heap-allocated instance member so you can return it out of a function, but I'd say you shouldn't ever be using a trick like this. What's wrong with using a stack to manage draw states?

Comment: @Jimmy Using a stack would force 2 lines of code for each state: 1 for pushing, 1 for pulling. I'm trying to get the push/pull calls out of the virtual Render() function, and into a non-virtual Draw() function which a user never interacts with directly. The user would just point to what states he wants saved.

Comment: You should post a sample of what you want code using your construct to look like.

Comment: Just as a side note, some recommended reading: http://diditwith.net/2008/01/01/BuildingDataOutOfThinAir.aspx

By the way, can't you just create extension methods for a stack? Depending how many resources you want to put in your line count reduction, you can use delegates, or create a disposable type and use using statement. But if what matters is the amount of typing, I would recommend Text Transformation Templates.

Answer (score 0):

I know you wanted to avoid delegates, but actually, this might be a much cleaner choice. For example, you can get code like this:

```
DrawingState state;

// ...
StateUtil.RestoreAfter(ref state, () => {

    state.Modify(...);

});

// state is now restored to the previous value
```

...with the following method:

```
public static class StateUtil
{
    public static void RestoreAfter<T>(ref T state, Action action) where T : struct
    {
        var copy = state;
        action();
        state = copy;
    }
}
```

You could use `ICloneable` instead of structs, and you can add multiple `ref` parameters to support restoring the state of multiple variables.

Comment: interesting idea. Do you think this would be cleaner than making a Restoration class and putting it in a using statement? Also, this would force me to de-privatize the draw function, and force the user to couple state preservation and rendering code. =\